# Page busy icon display only working on buttonclick

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

If got a  busy icon that displays whenever a button is clicked (the page dim's out and the icon displays. But I intended for this to happen whenever the page is busy and not just when a button is clicked. If tried to look at a few things for example the .ready function, but can't seem to get it working correctly... How do I set this in javascript/jquery to display whenever the page is busy and hide when the page is loaded fully? (I'm still a beginner in javascript).. Any help will be greatly appreciated..

This is how is it currently working (but only if I click on a button and not on anything else (like a checklist)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function ShowProgress() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var loading = $(".loading");
            loading.show();
            var overlay = $(".overlay");
            overlay.show();
        }, 200);
    }


    $('form').live("submit", function () {
        ShowProgress();
    });

    $(window).load(function () {
        $('.loading').hide();
        $('.overlay').hide();
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Are you facing problem on page load ? or for other events where page is busy.

Comment: for other events when the page is loading, as well as while the page loads. it only works for when I click on a button....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ASPX node `UpdateProgress`, in your MasterPage

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UP" DisplayAfter="10" runat="server">
   <ProgressTemplate>
      <!-- Insert your nodes 'loading' and 'overlay' here -->
   </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Then, when a Postback or a Callback is raised, your nodes will appear.

Answer (score 1):

what you need is the request interceptors. you can check [$.ajaxSetup](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/)